# How to create and send a google chat message with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-hangouts, google-chat

In my rails application, I am trying to create and send a google chat message using the api method `spaces.messages.create` as explained in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create). To do that, I will have to authenticate with a service account. I cant find examples on how to do this with ruby in reference to google chat. It seems like I will have to use the ruby cloud sdk but I cant find any reference to google chat [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby) . Instead of using the google cloud sdk, is it possible to do this with a ruby http client?

I will like to know how to authenticate using a service account and sending a message to google chat using the api method `spaces.messages.create`

Comment: You dont want to try to manually code service account authorizaotn.  Its much easer to use the standard client.   I would go with the Google cloud ruby client.

Comment: Do you know how to use the google ruby client to authenticate and make an api call to google chat. I cant find any example for that @DaImTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the steps are as follows:

1. Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) in order to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot` scope.

> Only supports service accounts. You can't authenticate user credentials using this scope.

2. Use the Service Account Auth Flow within [`googleauth`](https://rubygems.org/gems/googleauth/versions/0.4.1).

```rb
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('/path/to/service_account_json_key.json'),
  scope: scope)

authorizer.fetch_access_token!
```

3- Use the [`google-apis-chat_v1`](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-apis-chat_v1/v0.18.0/index.html) for performing the request.

In any case, I strongly review the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth) for Google Chats API, for a full understanding on how the authorization flow works.

##### Updated

###### Sample ruby client send message

```rb
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'google/apis/chat_v1'

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot'

authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('./credentials.json'),
  scope: scope)


chat =  Google::Apis::ChatV1::HangoutsChatService.new
msg = Google::Apis::ChatV1::Message.new(text: 'test')

chat.authorization = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open('./credentials.json'),
  scope: scope)
  
  
chat.create_space_message('spaces/XXXXXXXX', msg)
```

Comment: can you show me an example of how to make the api call for the method spaces.messages.create using the api gem ?

Comment: Do you reviewed the steps? Do you have a service account, reviewed the documentation and have an authorized ruby app?

Comment: I have reviewed the steps, have a service account and have an app with the api's enabled. I just cant find an example oh how to make google chat api calls in ruby.

Comment: @HakeemBaba Included an example, please up-vote or accept the answer if you consider it helpful

Comment: Can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486527/how-to-create-and-send-a-threaded-message-in-google-chat-with-ruby ?

Comment: @Emel How would one use this API to have a bot direct message a user? Does each user have a unique space id or is there a different endpoint that isn't listed in the documentation?